# Last row index of DataGridView returns wrong index

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to get the index of selected row in my gridview, but it doesn't work with the last selected row which returns the same index of the next-to-last row.

For example: if my gridview has 3 rows, the first row returns index 1, second row returns index 2 and third row returns index 2 too. If there are 100 rows, 99th row returns index 99 and 100th row will do the same. It makes no sense.

I already used all possible methods like `dataGridViewList.CurrentCell.RowIndex`, `dataGridViewList.CurrentRow.Index` and whatever you can imagine.

Note: I removed the standart blank last row by disabling user to add rows.

Comment: Maybe this works for you: if (rowIndex == numberOfRows) then lastRowIndex = rowIndex++;

Comment: @JCM I thought about that, but I want to understand why does this happen, since it makes no sense.

Comment: @GrantWinney I just realized what happened. I was trying to get the selected row index when I pressed enter, but after enter is pressed the selected row goes to next row. I was thinking that the row index was get before the selected row goest to the next row, but I just realized that the method takes the index after this.  I was almost going crazy with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to get the selected row index after enter be pressed. But when you pess enter in gridview, it selects the next row. I was thinking that the method would get the row index before it selects the next row, but it didn't. That's why the index did not start with 0 in first line, because it goes to second row after enter be pressed and only after that is when the method get the current selected row...

Now, all I have to do is to prevent DataGridView moving to next row on pressing ENTER key.